# Combining close points in graph

Tags: python, minima

So I have values given below. Here Index is frame numbers and A is the value related to that frame number.

```
Index   A
15  21.0
21  0.0
28  18.0
35  0.0
43  21.0
52  0.0
55  nan
60  nan
63  nan
64  nan
69  16.0
70  nan
72  15.0
79  nan
82  nan
91  0.0
94  8.0
99  0.0
100 0.0
106 15.0
113 0.0
119 nan
123 0.0
133 22.0
141 nan
142 10.0
148 0.0
152 8.0
154 nan
158 16.0
```

Using the above values, I am trying to plot a graph which gives me Maxima and Minima. Now there are some maxima and minima values that are very close and I want to combine it to one single point. I have attached an image of the graph.

Edit 1:- My expected output is, as shown in the 4th plot in the figure below, I want it to be a continuous graph and combine very close minima and maxima values to one value.
[Image of the Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0uRv.png)

Edit 2:-
My maxima values are as follows. I want to combine Index 69 and 72 as one single point as they are very close.

```
Index   A
15  21.0
28  18.0
43  21.0
55  nan
63  nan
69  16.0
72  15.0
82  nan
94  8.0
106 15.0
119 nan
133 22.0
142 10.0
152 8.0
158 16.0
```

Comment: I think you need to be a little more precise. Also could you share the expected output?

Comment: Read about curve smoothing and noise reduction

Comment: I have updated about the expected output in edit 1.I tried curve smoothing but it is removing some good maxima and minima points and moreover, it is changing my minima and maxima values because of which I am not able to keep a proper threshold. I have already removed some bad values assigning it to nan.